# MessageBox appears at wrong time

Tags: vb.net

I have a form which contains a `PctureBox`. When the user clicks this `PictureBox`, they will proceed to another form.

In the other form, I have a `DataGridView` and I have a search `TextBox` for the user to search content in the `DataGridView`. However I want to display "no record found" when the user enters something that is not in the database.

The `MessageBox` displays "no record found" however it also does this when the user first clicks on the `PictureBox` and the form loads.

Code:

```
Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged

    If Me.MasterlistTableAdapter1.FillBySearchProject(Me.DocumentDataSet.masterlist, TextBox3.Text)=0 Then

        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("No Record has been Found")

    End If

End Sub
```

When I created a `Button` this code works perfectly. The prompt only displays when no records are found on the search.

I don't want to use a `Button` to do the search. My search functions when a user only types several words, data found.

Comment: Displaying a message box for every single key press is grossly unpractical UI.  It should already be obvious to the user that the DGV is empty.  Or display the message in a StatusStrip.  And delete the Show() call, problem solved.

Comment: What do you mean by _My search functions when user only type just several words, data found._?

Comment: This is a common issue. While presetting data on a form, each preset control's events will fire during the load event. I usually add a Boolean IsLoaded flag that gets set after the initialization and test it in the handlers.

Comment: But as @HansPassant mentioned, using a message box for this is nasty. You are better to show "No Records Found" as an onscreen status somewhere. Usually where the data gets shown.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
Private Sub TextBox3_TextChanged_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.TextChanged

    If Not TextBox3.Text = "" Then

        If Me.MasterlistTableAdapter1.FillBySearchProject(Me.DocumentDataSet.masterlist, TextBox3.Text)=0 Then

            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("No Record has been Found")

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It doesnt work. The "no record has been found" still appears at wrong place